# jQuery can't show/hide element based on select option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am building a wordpress widget that allows users to build a simple form in the customizer preview.

Part of my form builder is to have a dropdown select input with several form elements listed (text, textarea, select, checkbox...etc), if the user selects either `select`, `checkbox` or `radio` as a form element, then a div containing a textarea where the user can list the options for these elements is shown via jQuery.

Obviously, the user can add unlimited elements, so I dynamically assign an id to each dropdown and each container div for the options so that I can show/hide them for each element that is added by the user.

Here is my simplified html markup showing the essence of what I have. You will see the dropdown where user can select the form element, and also the div containing a text area. Because each dropdown relates to a textarea, I have added jQuery code above them both to show/hide the textarea container:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var arr = ['select', 'checkbox', 'radio'];
    var thisForm = '#select-input-118 select.input_type';

    function showHideSelect() {
      var val = $(thisForm + ' option:selected').val();
      var selectOptions = $('#select-options-118')

      if (arr.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
        selectOptions.show();
      } else {
        selectOptions.hide();
      }
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      showHideSelect();

      $(thisForm).change(function() {
        showHideSelect();
      });
    });

  });

</script>
<p id="form_builder_input_type select-input-118" class="layers-form-item layers-column layers-span-9">
  <label for="widget-layers-widget-form_builder-3-input_type">Input Type</label>
  <select size="1" id="widget-layers-widget-form_builder-3-form_builders-118-input_type" name="widget-layers-widget-form_builder[3][form_builders][118][input_type]" placeholder="Select a form item" class="input_type">
    <option value="">Select a form item</option>
    <option value="text" selected="selected">
      Text </option>
    <option value="email">
      Email </option>
    <option value="textarea">
      Text Area </option>
    <option value="select">
      Drop Down Menu </option>
    <option value="checkbox">
      Checkbox </option>
    <option value="radio">
      Radio Buttons </option>
  </select>
</p>

<div id="select-options-118">
  <p id="select_options" class="layers-form-item">
    <label for="widget-layers-widget-form_builder-3-form_builders-118-select_options">Select Options</label>
  </p>
  <p style="background:#f5f5f5; padding:10px 20px; margin-bottom:20px;">One option per line</p>
  <textarea id="widget-layers-widget-form_builder-3-form_builders-118-select_options" name="widget-layers-widget-form_builder[3][form_builders][118][select_options]" placeholder="Add your options here" class="layers-text"></textarea>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

As the user can create unlimited number of form elements, the id's are dynamically inserted to the elements and into the jQuery code via php - I have just taken a snippet from the outputted html here. [You can see a jsfiddle also here](https://jsfiddle.net/46stb05y/)

The idea here being that for each dropdown, if the user selects either "select", "checkbox", or "radio". The div containing the options textarea shows, in all other cases it hides.

I have 2 questions:
1) My jQuery code isn't working and I can't see why
2) Is there a better way for me to code this, rather than have a snippet of jquery for every instance of dropdown/textarea? i.e. can I write a global piece of jQuery code that will add this function to all instances?

Comment: jQuery at jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/46stb05y/ appears to have `.ready()` inside of a `.ready()` handler ? The `.ready()` within `.ready()` handler should not be called

Comment: @guest271314 It's redundant, but also harmless

Comment: Yes well noticed @guest271314 - I've ammended the script on my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/46stb05y/1/ but still doesn't solve the issue

Comment: @SamSkirrow Note also, jQuery is not loaded into document at jsfiddles ; no element having `id` `#select-input-118` appears  at `html` ? `form_builder_input_type select-input-118` does not appear to be a valid `id`

Comment: Try re-checking `id`s of elements, jQuery selectors

Comment: @guest271314 - you're right - the issue was with my ID's - added a much simpler, but still unique class and that has fixed it. Is there a better way to do this though rather than have a block of jQuery script like this for every form element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your change event is on the form, not the element. If you set `thisform` to `'#widget-layers-widget-form_builder-3-form_builders-118-input_type'`, it works.

See https://jsfiddle.net/tghw/46stb05y/3/